# Calcular data com JavaScript ou de outra forma, até no excel?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-excel, jquery-datatables

Como chegar numa data fim a partir de uma data inicio multiplicando por N semanas, não levando em consideração a última semana do ano.
Até consigo calcular as datas, mas não consigo descontar a ultima semana.

Comment: Tá um pouquinho ampla a sua pergunta, né não? Escolhe uma linguagem. Dá pra fazer de formas diferentes em cada uma delas.

Answer (score 2):

Sugestão usando JavaScript:

```
function futuro(dataInicial, semanas) {
    var data = new Date(dataInicial); // para evitar mudar o objeto original
    var ano = data.getFullYear(); // saber o ano em que está
    var intervalo = semanas * 7 * 86400000; // calcular os milisegundos de diferença porque o JavaScript trabalha com milisegundos
    data.setTime(data.getTime() + intervalo); // aplicar o intervalo à data
    if (data.getFullYear() != ano) data.setTime(data.getTime() - 7 * 86400000); // tirar uma semana, caso o ano mude
    return data;
}

var hoje = new Date();
var dezembro = new Date(2016, 11, 1);

console.log(futuro(hoje, 2)); // dá Mon Jun 27 2016 06:55:25 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
console.log(futuro(dezembro, 6)); // dá Thu Jan 05 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j14w6kkv/1/

Answer (score 0):

Se for isso que precisa, fiz em Excel, porém como você não foi específico, considerei somente os dias pertencentes à última semana do ano, e não sete dias até 31 de dezembro inclusive.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As duas células finais devem ser formatadas para "data".

No caso da fórmula final, calcula-se a diferença entre as datas da última semana do ano e soma-se um, para pegar a quantidade de dias corretamente para serem descontados.

Se considerar a última semana diferente do que fiz, basta ajustar a fórmula.

Comment: Oi Cláudio, serviu para você amigo? Se sim, marque a resposta, por favor.